# LINQ Group inside a group

Tags: c#, linq

I have a datatable like this:

| date | Type | Agency | TotalCount | ABC_Count | DEF_Count | GHI_Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| JAN-2022 | X | B2X | 5 | 5 | 2 | 3 |
| JAN-2022 | X | C4A | 7 | 5 | 7 | 2 |
| FEB-2022 | X | B2X | 3 | 2 | 3 | 1 |
| FEB-2022 | X | C4A | 9 | 1 | 9 | 4 |
| MAR-2022 | X | B2X | 8 | 3 | 1 | 8 |
| MAR-2022 | X | C4A | 7 | 1 | 1 | 7 |
| JAN-2022 | Y | D5Y | 6 | 6 | 4 | 3 |
| JAN-2022 | Y | E7T | 7 | 3 | 7 | 2 |
| FEB-2022 | Y | D5Y | 4 | 2 | 4 | 1 |
| FEB-2022 | Y | E7T | 9 | 2 | 9 | 4 |
| MAR-2022 | Y | D5Y | 8 | 3 | 1 | 8 |
| MAR-2022 | Y | E7T | 8 | 1 | 1 | 8 |

Code:

```
public class GroupModel {
    public string LetterGroupName { get; set; }
    public List<LetterGroupData> LetterGroupData { get; set; }
}

public class LetterGroupData {
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public double TypeX_Ave { get; set; }
    public double TypeY_Ave { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }
}
```

My desired output would be a list of GroupModel `List<GroupModel>` and it should be something like this:

```
"GroupModel" : 
[
{
    "LetterGroupName" : "ABC",
    "LetterGroupData" : [
    {
         "Date": "JAN-2022",
         "TypeX_Ave":  40.0, //Sum ABC_Count for Type X / (Sum of TotalCount for JAN-2022 Type X + Y)
         "TypeY_Ave": 36.0,//Sum ABC_Count for Type Y / (Sum of TotalCount for JAN-2022 Type X + Y)
         "Total": 25 //sum of TotalCount for JAN-2022 Type X + Y
    },
    {
         "Date": "FEB-2022",
         "TypeX_Ave":  12.0, //Sum ABC_Count for Type X / (Sum of TotalCount for FEB-2022 Type X + Y)
         "TypeY_Ave": 16.0,//Sum ABC_Count for Type Y / (Sum of TotalCount for FEB-2022 Type X + Y)
         "Total": 25 //sum of TotalCount for FEB-2022 Type X + Y
    },//..and so on for MAR-2022
    ]
},
{
    "LetterGroupName" : "DEF",
    "LetterGroupData" : [
    {
         "Date": "JAN-2022",
         "TypeX_Ave":  36.0, //Sum DEF_Count for Type X / (Sum of TotalCount for JAN-2022 Type X + Y)
         "TypeY_Ave": 44.0,//Sum DEF_Count for Type Y / (Sum of TotalCount for JAN-2022 Type X + Y)
         "Total": 25 //sum of TotalCount for JAN-2022 Type X + Y
    },
    {
         "Date": "FEB-2022",
         "TypeX_Ave":  48.0, //Sum DEF_Count for Type X / (Sum of TotalCount for FEB-2022 Type X + Y)
         "TypeY_Ave": 52.0,//Sum DEF_Count for Type Y / (Sum of TotalCount for FEB-2022 Type X + Y)
         "Total": 25 //sum of TotalCount for FEB-2022 Type X + Y
    },//..and so on for MAR-2022
    ]
},//...and so on for LetterGroupName GHI
]
```

How do I achieve this result using only a single LINQ query?

Comment: Where *exactly* are you stuck trying this? It's not clear what you're actually asking.

Comment: For me matter of question is clear, the key phrase is "single LINQ query". Most of people would probably solve this in imperative way using loops, so with this in mind the question makes perfect sense to me.

Comment: @GennadiiSaltyshchak My point is that this question "doesn't show any research effort" (see the downvote reasons when hovering on the down arrow). That makes it unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implementation:

```
private static IReadOnlyCollection<GroupModel> GetGroups(IReadOnlyCollection<Dictionary<string, object>> input) =>
    (
        from groupName in new[] { "ABC", "DEF", "GHI" }
        select
            new GroupModel
            {
                LetterGroupName = groupName,
                LetterGroupData = (
                    from item in input
                    group item by (string)item["date"] into itemGroup
                    let total = itemGroup.Sum(item => (int)item["TotalCount"])
                    select new LetterGroupData
                    {
                        Date = itemGroup.Key,
                        TypeX_Ave = (double)itemGroup
                            .Where(item => (string)item["Type"] == "X")
                            .Sum(item => (int)item[groupName + "_Count"])
                            / total * 100,
                        TypeY_Ave = (double)itemGroup
                            .Where(item => (string)item["Type"] == "Y")
                            .Sum(item => (int)item[groupName + "_Count"])
                            / total * 100,
                        Total = total,
                    }).ToList()
            }
    ).ToList();
```

Usage:

```
var input =
    new Dictionary<string, object>[]
    {
        new()
        {
            ["date"] = "JAN-2022",
            ["Type"] = "X",
            ["Agency"] = "B2X",
            ["TotalCount"] = 5,
            ["ABC_Count"] = 5,
            ["DEF_Count"] = 2,
            ["GHI_Count"] = 3,
        },
        new()
        {
            ["date"] = "JAN-2022",
            ["Type"] = "X",
            ["Agency"] = "C4A",
            ["TotalCount"] = 7,
            ["ABC_Count"] = 5,
            ["DEF_Count"] = 7,
            ["GHI_Count"] = 2,
        },
        new()
        {
            ["date"] = "JAN-2022",
            ["Type"] = "Y",
            ["Agency"] = "B2X",
            ["TotalCount"] = 6,
            ["ABC_Count"] = 6,
            ["DEF_Count"] = 4,
            ["GHI_Count"] = 3,
        },
        new()
        {
            ["date"] = "JAN-2022",
            ["Type"] = "Y",
            ["Agency"] = "C4A",
            ["TotalCount"] = 7,
            ["ABC_Count"] = 3,
            ["DEF_Count"] = 7,
            ["GHI_Count"] = 2,
        },
        // ...
    };

var groups = GetGroups(input);
// groups.Dump();
```

[.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/56CbbO)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you really want getting data from a datatable :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("date", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Type", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Agency", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("TotalCount", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("ABC_Count", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("DEF_Count", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("GHI_Count", typeof(int));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "JAN - 2022", "X", "B2X", 5, 5, 2, 3 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "JAN - 2022", "X", "C4A", 7, 5, 7, 2 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "FEB - 2022", "X", "B2X", 3, 2, 3, 1 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "FEB - 2022", "X", "C4A", 9, 1, 9, 4 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "MAR - 2022", "X", "B2X", 8, 3, 1, 8 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "MAR - 2022", "X", "C4A", 7, 1, 1, 7 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "JAN - 2022", "Y", "D5Y", 6, 6, 4, 3 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "JAN - 2022", "Y", "E7T", 7, 3, 7, 2 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "FEB - 2022", "Y", "D5Y", 4, 2, 4, 1 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "FEB - 2022", "Y", "E7T", 9, 2, 9, 4 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "MAR - 2022", "Y", "D5Y", 8, 3, 1, 8 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "MAR - 2022", "Y", "E7T", 8, 1, 1, 8 });

            List<GroupModel> groups = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("Agency"))
                .Select(x => new GroupModel() { 
                    LetterGroupName = x.Key,
                    LetterGroupData = x.Select(y => new LetterGroupData() { 
                        Date = y.Field<string>("date"), 
                        TypeX_Ave = x.Where(z => z.Field<string>("Type") == "X").Select(a => a.Field<int>("ABC_Count")).Sum(),
                        TypeY_Ave = x.Where(z => z.Field<string>("Type") == "Y").Select(a => a.Field<int>("ABC_Count")).Sum(),
                        Total = x.Sum(a => a.Field<int>("ABC_Count"))
                    }).ToList(),
                }).ToList();

        }
    }
    public class GroupModel
    {
        public string LetterGroupName { get; set; }
        public List<LetterGroupData> LetterGroupData { get; set; }
    }

    public class LetterGroupData
    {
        public string Date { get; set; }
        public double TypeX_Ave { get; set; }
        public double TypeY_Ave { get; set; }
        public int Total { get; set; }
    }

}
```

If you really mean that you want totals by date you have to go back to the datatable like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("date", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Type", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Agency", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("TotalCount", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("ABC_Count", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("DEF_Count", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("GHI_Count", typeof(int));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "JAN - 2022", "X", "B2X", 5, 5, 2, 3 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "JAN - 2022", "X", "C4A", 7, 5, 7, 2 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "FEB - 2022", "X", "B2X", 3, 2, 3, 1 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "FEB - 2022", "X", "C4A", 9, 1, 9, 4 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "MAR - 2022", "X", "B2X", 8, 3, 1, 8 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "MAR - 2022", "X", "C4A", 7, 1, 1, 7 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "JAN - 2022", "Y", "D5Y", 6, 6, 4, 3 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "JAN - 2022", "Y", "E7T", 7, 3, 7, 2 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "FEB - 2022", "Y", "D5Y", 4, 2, 4, 1 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "FEB - 2022", "Y", "E7T", 9, 2, 9, 4 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "MAR - 2022", "Y", "D5Y", 8, 3, 1, 8 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "MAR - 2022", "Y", "E7T", 8, 1, 1, 8 });

            List<GroupModel> groups = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("Agency"))
                .Select(x => new GroupModel() { 
                    LetterGroupName = x.Key,
                    LetterGroupData = x.Select(y => new LetterGroupData() {
                        Date = y.Field<string>("date"),
                        TypeX_Ave = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(z => z.Field<string>("Type") == "X" && z.Field<string>("date") == y.Field<string>("date")).Select(a => a.Field<int>("ABC_Count")).Sum(),
                        TypeY_Ave = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(z => z.Field<string>("Type") == "Y" && z.Field<string>("date") == y.Field<string>("date")).Select(a => a.Field<int>("ABC_Count")).Sum(),
                        Total = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(z => (z.Field<string>("Type") == "X" || z.Field<string>("Type") == "Y") && z.Field<string>("date") == y.Field<string>("date")).Select(a => a.Field<int>("ABC_Count")).Sum(),
                    }).ToList(),
                }).ToList();

        }
    }
    public class GroupModel
    {
        public string LetterGroupName { get; set; }
        public List<LetterGroupData> LetterGroupData { get; set; }
    }

    public class LetterGroupData
    {
        public string Date { get; set; }
        public double TypeX_Ave { get; set; }
        public double TypeY_Ave { get; set; }
        public int Total { get; set; }
    }

}
```